# How can i change the bytes values in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte, converters

I'm learning Python 3 and i'm trying to make a Caesar Cypher Algorithm. I'm taking a string with commandline input and then I want to change the hexa bytes values (I mean add or substract an integer on it) and finally return the modified string.

```
stringToDecode = "L|k€y+*^*zo‚*€kvsno|*k€om*vo*zk}}*cyvksr"
for i in range(256):
  print('%i: %s' % (i, repr(''.join([chr((ord(c)+i)%256) for c in stringToDecode]))))
```

Here is what i managed to do atm but it doesn't works really well. Thx a lot for reading! :)

Comment: Good lord that is terrible formatting. Please don't make Python look like Perl!!

Comment: Well, sry, Python is kinda new for me, I've always used C/C++/C# before. So feel free to give me some advices if my formatting suck so much ^^.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your question. You want to increment the `ord()` value of each character by the same amount in order to implement a Caesar Cypher, right?

Comment: That's it! But with my code it doesn't works fine.

Comment: With my code the result of line 246 is:

**246: 'Bra¢o! Tu peu\x10 ¢alider a¢ec le pass Yolaihu\n'**  .

But if I replace the first line by :

**stringToDecode ='\x4c\x7c\x6b\x80\x79\x2b\x2a\x5e\x7f\x2a\x7a\x6f\x7f\x82\x2a\x80\x6b\x76\x73\x6e\x6f\x7c\x2a\x6b\x80\x6f\x6d\x2a\x76\x6f\x2a\x7a\x6b\x7d\x7d\x2a\x63\x79\x76\x6b\x73\x72\x7f\x14\x0a'**   

(Whitch is exactly the same but in hexa)
Then the result is :  

**246: 'Bravo! Tu peux valider avec le pass Yolaihu\n\x00'**  

Whitch is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit easier to read. Remember, you usually spend at least twice as long reading your code than writing it, so why not make it easier to read :).

```
stringToDecode = "L|k€y+*^*zo‚*€kvsno|*k€om*vo*zk}}*cyvksr"
for i in range(256):
    list_comp = [chr((ord(c)+i)%256) for c in stringToDecode]
    joined_list = ''.join(list_comp)
    new_val = repr(joined_list) # you shouldn't need this
    print('%i: %s' % (i, new_val))
```